# Zend Session, Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable and Asynchronous Requests

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I am using Zend Session combined with Zend_Auth and Session Namespaces in the following fashion:

**application.ini**

```
    resources.session.saveHandler.class = "Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable"
    resources.session.saveHandler.options.name = "session"
    resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary = "id"
    resources.session.saveHandler.options.modifiedColumn = "modified"
    resources.session.saveHandler.options.dataColumn = "data"
    resources.session.saveHandler.options.lifetimeColumn = "lifetime"
```

**Bootstrap**

```
     /**
     * Start session 
     */
    public function _initCoreSession() {
        $this->bootstrap('db');
        $this->bootstrap('session');
        Zend_Session::start();
    }
```

While the Zend_Auth seems to work fine, the other session namespaces seem to behave oddly.

I use several Asynchronous requests (using jQuery).

-Init (intializes an array into the session)

```
    $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('scanner');
    $ns->unsetAll();
    $ns->pages = array();
```

-Loop (puts stuff into array, this part is called 1 to n times)

```
    //Fetch the Session Namespace
    $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('scanner');
    //Set scanned page to true
    $ns->pages[$this->getRequest()->getParam('nextUrl')] = true;
```

-Finalize (processes the array)

```
    //Fetch the Session Namespace
    $ns = new Zend_Session_Namespace('scanner');
    //Do stuff with $ns->pages
```

However somewhere in the calls to loop the pages variable seems to be reset (and thus null).

This works in the default session behaviour, but it starts to fail when i set Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable.

****EDIT****

As a response to the first answer (cause it required a code block)

I am using $.post to make requests to my application. Where it sends a request with data (an URL) to the application, and it receives a status update and an url to request next. And this loops around until it receives no next url.

**jQuery code used**

```
    function scanUrl(url)
    {
        $.post("http://www.example.com/scan/scanurl", { nextUrl: url },
       function(data) 
       {
         updateView(data);

         if(data.nextUrl != null)
             scanUrl(data.nextUrl);
         else
             finalize();
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you pass the session id with your asymc request? if i did not misunderstood and you are calling stuff like this:

$.ajax({
'url' : 'http://something',
...
})

you need to add a 'data' section where you have:

sessionIdVariable=your-current-session-id

Comment: Surely this will be in the session cookie?

Comment: So your saying if i posted a variable called sessionIdVariable with my current sessionID the application would pickup on it? PS. i added a code block with my JS request loop.